# How can I fix my format error in my program

Tags: python, format

I've tried to fix this problem for awhile now, I've tried adding a str to it and couple other random things. The error I get is the unsupported format string passed to NoneType.**format**.

```
print('{0:<6}{1:<20}{2:<16}{3:<14}{4:<13}{5:.2f}'.format(
    eachID,
    empDict[eachID][0],
    date,
    empDict[eachID][2],
    empDict[eachID][3],
    calculatePay(eachID,empDict)))
```

Comment: Not enough info. Make [mcve] with values for each of the variables. One or more of the format strings is invalid but can’t tell which one.

Comment: Looks like same question has been asked before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55963526/python-typeerror-unsupported-format-string-passed-to-nonetype-format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be that at least one of your format arguments is `None`.

Running

```py
print('{0:<6}{1:<20}{2:<16}{3:<14}{4:<13}{5:.2f}'.format(1,2,3,4,5,6))
```

works fine for me, so the format string doesn't seem to be the problem. You could try to print out each argument by itself to see where the error occurs.

---

Not directly related to your problem, but since Python 3.6 you can use f-strings to simplify the expression:

```py
print(f'{eachID:<6}{empDict[eachID][0]}...')
```